# Tensorflow training classifier

Tags: python

I am having this issue. can someone please help me on this?

File "D:\pythonMain\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: ; No such file or directory

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a minimal example that people can actually help with. Since we can't see your code, we can't just magically guess what fixes you might need or be 100% sure about the problem. It seems to me that in your code somewhere, you might be passing in an empty path to a file or directory. This is because of the `Failed to create a directory: ;` part of your error. As you can see, there's no directory listed, which means that there is likely supposed to be one specified somewhere that you forgot.

Comment: Is it possible TensorFlow is not properly installed on your machine? I once thought I had TensorFlow installed on my Windows machine, but go this error when trying to run it in PyCharm. Windows requires a little bit of a different installation procedure - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83vR1Nz3dHA